# Putting a value from an input data file into 'Set Label'

Tags: gnuplot

I'm plotting an animated surface in gnuplot and want to read in an average or sum of the mapped z values and include this in a label to be printed in the plot, so that I get a running total updated as the GIF progresses. It's probably straightforward, but I'm a "gnu"bie, so to speak, and find this system pretty confusing!

I've tried putting the running sum and average numbers in additional columns ...

splot 'output3.dat' index i:i using 1:2:(column(3), TD1 = strcol(4), TD2 = strcol(5)) with pm3d

but this doesn't plot, and the string variables TD1, TD2 don't seem to exist outside the splot command.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We cannot reproduce your case, because we don't have your data and your full script. Please show some example data and the resulting graph. Otherwise it will be difficult to help. I assume you want to plot column3, so it should be last in the paranthesis. Which version of gnuplot are you running?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The command you show would indeed set variables TD1 and TD2 globally if you change the order of clauses in the serial evaluation expression (the comma-separated sub-expressions):

```
splot 'output3.dat' index i:i using 1:2:(TD1 = strcol(4), TD2 = strcol(5), column(3)) with pm3d
```

However, if the idea is to create a label using `set label` that will appear as part of the resulting graph, this won't work. The `set label` command would have to be executed before the `splot` command, so TD1 and TD2 will not have the correct values yet.

There is an alternative that might serve you better.  Instead of trying to put this dynamically evaluate information in a label, put it in the plot title.  Unlike a label, the plot title is evaluated *after* the corresponding plot is generated, so any variables set or updated by that plot will be current. [caveat: this is true for current gnuplot (version 5.4) but was not always true. If you have an older gnuplot version the title is evaluated before the plot rather than after].

Since current gnuplot also allows you to place the individual plot titles somewhere other than in the key proper, you have the same freedom that you would with a label to position the text anywhere on the output page. For example, if you want to sum the values in column 3 of the data file and print the total as part of a title above the resulting plot:

```
 SUM = 0
 splot 'foo.dat' using 1:2:(SUM = SUM+column(3), column(3)) with linespoints title 'foo.dat', \
       keyentry title = sprintf("Points sum to %g", SUM) at screen 0.5 0.9
```

I used a separate `keyentry` clause because this allows to omit the sample line segment that would otherwise be generated, but it would also be possible to make this the title of the plot itself if you want that sample line.
[image]